# For loop of python graphics

Tags: python, for-loop, graphics

I am working on optimizing my code for a school project I have. I am attempting to draw a grid using the Python graphics library. When I run the loop, it continues to add rows, but the x1 and x2 values do not go back to their original values like I need them to. It extends the next row at the (x2, y2) point of the last square of the row. Any insight into how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated!

```
import random, graphics
from graphics import *

x1 = 5
x2 = 65
y1 = 5
y2 = 65

def make_square(x1, x2, y1, y2):

    location = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(x1, y1), graphics.Point(x2, y2))
    location.draw(win)
    
win = graphics.GraphWin("Minesweeper", 545, 570)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(250, 249, 246))

for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        make_square(x1, x2, y1, y2)
        x1 = x1 + 60
        x2 = x2 + 60
    y1 = y1 + 60
    y2 = y2 + 60
     
win.getMouse() # Pause to view result, click on window to close it
win.close() # Close window when done
```

Comment: Could you add a little more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, at the start of drawing a new row, you want to reset `x1` and `x2`, which makes sense, because the next row would start at the same x position as the previous row. Did you try adding your `x1 = 5` and `x2 = 65` to the start of the outer for loop, instead of defining them outside the loop?

Look at it this way: you define `y` outside the outer loop, because it loops over rows, you define `x` outside the inner loop, because it loops over columns:

```
import random, graphics
from graphics import *


def make_square(x1, x2, y1, y2):

    location = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(x1, y1), graphics.Point(x2, y2))
    location.draw(win)
    

win = graphics.GraphWin("Minesweeper", 545, 570)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(250, 249, 246))

y1 = 5
y2 = 65
for i in range(9):
    x1 = 5
    x2 = 65
    for j in range(9):
        make_square(x1, x2, y1, y2)
        x1 = x1 + 60
        x2 = x2 + 60
    y1 = y1 + 60
    y2 = y2 + 60
     
win.getMouse() # Pause to view result, click on window to close it
win.close() # Close window when done
```